# wiki like architecture in PHP?

Tags: architecture, wiki

I am implementing a web-application in which I need functionality where users should be able to edit pages, posts and comments.

I am on LAMP stack.

I have DB tables like topic and posts users etc.

How should I proceed on doing this?

Comment: So you want a pre-built solution, or suggetions/tips on rolling your own?

Comment: Suggestions on rolling my own or something I can build on top of.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a wiki solution written in PHP, try [mediawiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki).

Comment: this is not wiki-like, this is the true WIKI :)